# Android Wear - Launching Google Play on Phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I have followed the sample here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearVerifyRemoteApp. I ran the app on Wear Emulator (Android 6.0.1). I reached the point where the app is not installed on phone and want to launch the app link on Google Play on the device:

```
// Create Remote Intent to open Play Store listing of app on remote device.
            Intent intentAndroid =
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                            .setData(Uri.parse(PLAY_STORE_APP_URI));

            RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    intentAndroid,
                    mResultReceiver);
```

I attached the debugger and, yes, I reached this line, but nothing happens. Google Play is not launched on the phone. I am sure I am connected to the phone as other notifications from the phone (real device) appears on the emulator.

**Edit:**

Not clear why but connection from the phone to the emulator is really buggy. It's really frustrating and the issue was solved but disconnecting and reconnecting many times.

Comment: What's the value of `PLAY_STORE_APP_URI`?

Comment: market://details?id=com.example.android.wearable.wear.wearverifyremoteapp

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to have a phone APK and a watch APK in your Android Wear app then you must use the [Multi-APK delivery method](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html). which is, as mentioned,

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to different device configurations.

If you haven't done so, try enabling **Advanced mode** in your application's APK files tab to be able to publish multiple APKs for your app.

For more information, see [Packaging and Distributing Wear Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html).

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? He's probably already using multi-APK delivery, and is including the `RemoteIntent` call to ensure both APKs are installed - but is having trouble with it.